# Custom Module Controller not working

Tags: magento-1, controllers, routing

I have built a custom Module for my client's site where I have been putting my overrides and observers, built a helper class, etc. It has been working fine to now.

I am trying to add a Controller, however, and it doesn't seem to be working.

I have followed a few different Tuts that all point to a simple implementation:

in my config, I added:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
...
<frontend>
    <routers>
        <flamanhelper>
            <use>standard</use>
            <args>
                <module>Flaman_FlamanHelper</module>
                <frontName>flamanhelper</frontName>
            </args>
        </flamanhelper>
    </routers>   
</frontend>
</config>
```

my Index Controller /(located at: /app/code/local/Flaman/FlamanHelper/Controllers/IndexController.php

```
class Flaman_FlamanHelper_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action {
    public function indexAction(){
        echo "flaman helper controller";
    }
    public function geolocationAction(){
        echo "you are here: ";
    }
}
```

so should my URLs not be

```
http://<domain>/flamanhelper
http://<domain>/flamanhelper/index/geolocation
```

because I just get 404s :(

any insight will be appreciated

Edited: to add Controller path

Comment: where is the Flaman_FlamanHelper_IndexController class located in your module?

Comment: /app/code/local/Flaman/FlamanHelper/Controllers/IndexController.php

Comment: try using a lower case "c" on "Controllers" so it becomes "controllers"

Comment: GET OUT OF TOWN - that worked

Answer (score 3):

try using a lower case `c` on `Controllers` so it becomes `controllers`

Comment: ha ha, no problem. Feel free to accept the answer if all is working OK.

Comment: am not sure how to do that. I'm too newb to affect the upvotes apparently. ... where is the 'accept' button

Comment: Ah you may require 10+ rep to accept an answer. This should be a tick below the voting icons.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your controller folder should be named `controllers` instead of `Controllers`

Comment: Thank you, I was using another module for reference and THEY had a capital C on their controller

Comment: @seanyeomans well there can be a `Controller` folder but it is different than the `controllers` folder, see here: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/6438/difference-between-controller-and-controllers